# Pass Textbox value from view to Controller on button click without using form in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to pass the value entered in my text box to a controller class on click of  submit buttton. I do not want to use Form or I do not have a model class for this field. How it can be achieved?
Below is the sample code for your reference

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;width:95%;">My header</td>
<td>
<select>
<option value="Choose">Select</option>
<option value="val1">val1</option>
<option value="val2">val2</option>
<option value="val3">val3</option>
</select>
</td>

<td>
<input type ="text" id="searchField" name="searchFieldText">
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" style="color:black;background-color:rgb(216, 214, 208)" value="Search" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ExecuteSearch", "MyController",new { <!--I want to pass the textbox value as param here-->})'" />
</td>
<td style="text-align:right;width:10%;">@Html.ActionLink("LOGOUT", "logout")</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: First question: Why? Second question: Have you looked into using javascript?

Comment: @AndyRefuerzo Thanks for your question.  I want to get the entered text value in Controller and search for the entered value in my Database

Comment: I looked into javascript but I am not able to call the Javascript function from Url.Action Method

Answer (score 0):

There are various options to achieve the same. You can take help of Jquery like this:

```
<a href='@url.action("LOGOUT","logout")?someParameter=$('#searchField').val()' >Text for Link Name</a>
```

On controller level you have to add string parameter to the logout method. Like:

```
Public ActionResult Logout(string someParameter)
{
  //your code
}
```

**Using AJAX**

Below code snippet will work using ajax call

```
<div class="row">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;width:95%;">My header</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="Choose">Select</option>
                    <option value="val1">val1</option>
                    <option value="val2">val2</option>
                    <option value="val3">val3</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="text" id="searchField" name="searchFieldText"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" style="color:black;background-color:rgb(216, 214, 208)" value="Search" onclick="submitClick()" />
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right;width:10%;">@Html.ActionLink("LOGOUT", "logout")</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
   function submitClick()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../MyController/ExecuteSearch?someParameter=" + $('#searchField').val(),
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
              // your custom code
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help !! But I wanted to achieve this with submit button instaed of hyper link. How is that done?

Comment: okay,if you want to do with submit button without using FORM, then you can achieve with ajax calls. If you need, I can update answer with sample ajax call.